# Using words for a song from a book my great grandfather wrote

Tags: copywriting

My great grandfather wrote a book in 1887 that is in the Library of Congress.Can I use some of the words he wrote in a song?

Answer (score 4):

All works published in the US before 1927 have lost their copyright protection and are now in the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain_in_the_United_States). So anyone (including you) can do whatever they want with his words.